# Why can't I run a JApplet in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, japplet

I am learning Java from the Oracle documentation page: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html

I am using Intellij on Linux Mint and I had no problems until I got to JApplets. Whenever I am trying to run my code now I get the following error:

Error: Could not find or load main class sun.applet.AppletViewer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.applet.AppletViewer

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This sounds like you are missing a required dependency that would provide the `sun.applet.AppletViewer` class that your code depends on. The way to resolve this will depend on how you are building your code (command line, Maven project, etc).

Comment: What JDK version do you use?

Comment: Applets are no longer supported in recent versions of Java and the browsers. You really should stop learning them and learn a different way to build Java applications instead.